# Self assessment expenses - billing date or payment date?

Tags: united-kingdom, expenses, self-assessment

For my HMRC Self Assessment (expenses), I am wondering if I should put the date of transactions as the billing date or the payment date. Or doesn't it matter as long as I'm consistant?

Comment: `date of transactions` As this is the day you paid. When the payment out of the bank is because of the lag in clearing. Did you call up HMRC to ask ?

Comment: See the HMRC page about Cash Basis: https://www.gov.uk/simpler-income-tax-cash-basis

Comment: So as long as I'm using cash basis, I should use the date money was received or paid out?

Comment: Are you talking about "_the day I bought a train ticket_" vs. "_the day the entry appeared on my statement_" as a couple of comments seem to think, or "_the day I incurred the expense_" vs. "_the day I was reimbursed by my company_" (which could be a month or more later)?

Comment: I was particularly thinking of things like a phone bill, where you would have a billing date of say 1st August, but the payment coming out of the bank on say the 15th August for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're running a self-employed business with a significant turnover (more than £150k), you are entitled to use [cash basis](https://www.gov.uk/simpler-income-tax-cash-basis/who-can-use-cash-basis) accounting for your tax return, which means you would put the date of transactions as the payment date rather than the billing date or the date a debt is incurred.

For payments which have a lag, e.g. a cheque that needs to be paid in or a bank transfer that takes a few days, you might also need to choose between multiple payment dates, e.g. when you initiated the payment or when it took effect. You can pick one [as long as you're consistent](https://www.gov.uk/simpler-income-tax-cash-basis/income-and-expenses-under-cash-basis):

> You can choose how you record when money is received or 
>   paid (eg the date the money enters your account or the date a cheque
>   is written) but you must use the same method each tax year.